# NSInternalInconsistencyException: database disk image is malformed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

Anyone have any idea what could cause this kind of problem? I don't have any additional context but am confused as to how this could be happening. For what it's worth, I try to add our persistent store to the coordinator on app launch and if unsuccessful, remove the database file and recreate it. Thank you.

`NSInternalInconsistencyException: Fatal error. The database at /var/mobile/Applications/1A2D247A-AB6C-4FDF-A9A6-31935BB76188/Documents/Tumblr.sqlite is corrupted. SQLite error code:11, 'database disk image is malformed'`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest make sure you close the database when you're done using it, or if you're keeping the database connection open for any reason, make sure that your app delegate's `applicationWillTerminate` closes the database and cleans up, as appropriate.